# How can I make floated link clickable for whole row?

Tags: html, css, css-float

CodePen is here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKVMoY

```css
ul {
  width: 40%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
span:last-of-type {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <span>New York</span>
      <span>$489</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <span>New York</span>
      <span>$489</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>New York</span>
    <span>$489</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>New York</span>
    <span>$489</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Why isn't the floated element underlined?

How can I make it clickable for space between the spans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just add `display: block;` to the anchor tags in order to make the entire row clickable. I'm not exactly sure why the floated element removes the underline.

Comment: Float removes underline because text decoration is not propagated to out-of-flow descendants.

Answer (score 1):

**Why isn't the floated element underlined?**

[16.3.1 Underlining, overlining, striking, and blinking: the '`text-decoration`' property](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#propdef-text-decoration)

> Note that text decorations are not propagated to floating and absolutely positioned descendants, nor to the contents of atomic inline-level descendants such as inline blocks and inline tables.

To fix that, you can set `text-decoration: inherit` on the floated span.

```
span:last-of-type {
  float: right;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}
```

**How can I make it clickable for space between the spans?**

You can set the `<a>` to `display:block`, it will the occupies the entire width available.

```
a {
  display: block;
}
```

```css
ul {
  width: 40%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
a {
  display: block;
}
span:last-of-type {
  float: right;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <span>New York</span>
      <span>$489</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <span>New York</span>
      <span>$489</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>New York</span>
    <span>$489</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>New York</span>
    <span>$489</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="whole-row-link">
   <li>
      <a href="#"></a>
         <span>New York</span>
         <span>$489</span>

   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="#"></a>
         <span>New York</span>
         <span>$489</span>

   </li>
</ul>

ul.whole-row-link li {
  position: relative;
}
ul.whole-row-link li a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0
}
```

Comment: Or you can add display:block to the anchor however I answered the question this way as you may also want to throw some more things into the list item like another div or photo and this is how you would do it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make the space between the link clickable but it stillls looks weird when you dont have underline.

I used the flexbox to acheive the effect of the clickable.

```
`http://codepen.io/Ebeldev/pen/BKVMwP`
```